# CSS multiple class selector to control :hover effect

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a div with a :hover pseudo-class that applies many CSS effects to indicate to the user that they are hovering over it.

How do I disable the CSS effect when the user hovers over it by adding a .disable class?

http://jsfiddle.net/nQUSn/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all browsers except IE < 9:

Change `.a:hover {` to `.a:not(.disable):hover {`

Comment: how about if I want to .a:not(.disable , .unselectable") , it is not working

Comment: I believe you can chain it: `.a:not(.disable):not(.unselectable)`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a selector a.disable:hover that resets the styles on that anchor element.  For example, if your a:hover css was:

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

And the link color is normally blue, your disable CSS could look like:

```
a.disable:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in his case. It seems the background property doesn't get reset.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use the ".disable" class. You can chain the `:disabled` pseudo-class with the `:hover` pseudo-class:

```
elem {
  color : blue;
}
elem:hover {
  color : lightblue;
}
elem:disabled, elem:disabled:hover {
  color : grey;
}
```